# Disabling input button if required fields are empty

Tags: javascript

so i have seen a recent post about disabling an input button if the required fields aren't filled in. I am not very good at javascript but i copied the code and changed to my own variables. the thing is that it doesn't work. can someone help me out here.

The question: how do i disable the input button if the required fields are not filled. Once it is filled it will be available again "orange".

```js
(function() {
  $('form > input').keyup(function() {

    var empty = false;
    $('form > input').each(function() {
      if ($(this).val() == '') {
        empty = true;
      }
    });

    if (empty) {
      $('#register').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
      $('#register').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
  });
})()
```

```css
input[type="submit"][disabled] {
  color: gray;
  border-color: gray;
  background-color: white;
}

.ajax-button {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}

.submit {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 2px solid #FFa500;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #FFa500;
  font-size: 17px;
  cursor: pointer !important;
  outline: none;
  background-color: white;
}

.submit:hover {
  background-color: orange;
  color: white;
}

.loading {
  font-size: 0;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 0;
  border: 3px solid #FFa500;
  border-bottom: 3px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0);
  border-left: 3px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0);
  background-color: transparent !important;
  animation-name: rotateAnimation;
  -webkit-animation-name: wk-rotateAnimation;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-delay: 0.2s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes rotateAnimation {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes wk-rotateAnimation {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.fabutton {
  color: #FFa500;
  font-size: 18px !important;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -9px;
  margin-top: -9px;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0) !important;
  transform: scaleX(0) !important;
}

.finish {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1) !important;
  transform: scaleX(1) !important;
}

.hide-loading {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) !important;
  transform: rotate(0deg) !important;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0) !important;
  transform: scale(0) !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 button-holder" style="margin-top:30px;">
      <div class="ajax-button">
        <div class="fa fa-check done fabutton"></div>
        <div class="fa fa-close failed fabutton"></div>
        <input id="submit" class="submit" type="submit" value="submit" disabled="disabled" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </form>
</div>
<script>
</script>
```

Comment: Use `prop()` for setting disabled: `$('#register').prop('disabled', true)` (or `false`)

Comment: PS 1: you don't open a form tag. First solve this bug and update your question. PS 2: use a snippet for your code.

Comment: @H.Pauwelyn i have a form tag now around the button however it still doesnt work.

Comment: Could you update your question?

Comment: I think it's `$('form input')`and not `$('form > input')`. See [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). They use JS but it's

Comment: If you took this from a working example. You should troubleshoot what you did wrong with that.

Answer (score 0):

Probally `$('form > input')` is returning empty. There's no `<form>` tag open.

Open a form tag between

```
<div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="row">
```

this way:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <form>
              <div class="row">
```

Comment: i did add one, it still did nothing. :3

Comment: Well, try to put some `console.log()` to see what's happening. Check out `$('form > input')` inside `keyup` func and `this` inside `each` func loop.

Comment: Sorry amigo, i am a beginner with javascript and i don't know how to check this. i have to bring this up with my teacher.

Answer (score 0):

Let try with:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[type=text]').on('keyup', function(){
   var empty = false, val = '';
   val = $(this).val();
   if (val.length) {
    empty = false;
   } else {
    empty = true;
   }
   if (empty) {
    $('#submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
   } else {
    $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
   }
  });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
 <form>
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 button-holder" style="margin-top:30px;">
       <input type="text" name="" required="*" id="register">
        <div class="ajax-button">
          <div class="fa fa-check done fabutton"></div>
          <div class="fa fa-close failed fabutton"></div>
          <input id="submit" class="submit" type="submit" value="submit" disabled="disabled" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
 </form>
</div>
<script>
</script>
```

Comment: hey it's working, However only if 1 field if filled, how about if i want 3 fields for an example? : )